# It doesn't work due to dependency issues. Please tell me how

Tags: android-studio, firebase-mlkit

I am someone who has just started in Android Studio. I am currently writing a face recognition program using ml-kit. I added a dependency in the app module, but it does not work.

```java
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.FirebaseVisionFace;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.FirebaseVisionFaceDetector;
import com.google.firebase.ml.vision.FirebaseVisionFaceDetectorOptions;

// Here are the Gradle dependencies:
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.0.3")
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:20.0.1")
```

I keep getting errors here. Can anyone help me?

"The following error occurred: /Users/kim-young-kwang/AndroidStudioProjects/project2/app/src/main/java/com/example/project2/YourAnalyzer.java:6: error: cannot find symbol import com. google.firebase.ml.vision.FirebaseVisionFace;. If you know under what circumstances this error occurs, please explain."

Comment: Firebase ML Vision is deprecated by the new ML Kit, so I'd suggest you to migrate. https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection